# Referring to a table variable from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sql-server-2012

Declaring a table variable with database name throws the following error.

> The type name 'dbname.dbo.TableType' contains more than the maximum
> number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.

```
Declare @cutoffDtes as dbname.dbo.TableType
```

However, the same works when I do the following

```
use dbname
Declare @cutoffDtes as dbo.TableType
```

Is there a way to declare the variable along with database name?

Comment: *"Is there a way to declare the variable along with database name?"* No, as the error tells you, you can't have more than one prefix on a user defined data type; the schema. You also can't create a `SYNONYM` for them, as they are not a [supported object type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) for them. You'll need to create the `TYPE` in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/registering-user-defined-types-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is pretty clear (once you find the reference) that user defined types are available only within a single database:

> **Using UDTs Across Databases**
>
> UDTs are by definition scoped to a single database. Therefore, a UDT defined in one database cannot be used in a column definition in another database. In order to use UDTs in multiple databases, you must execute the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` and `CREATE TYPE` statements in each database on identical assemblies. Assemblies are considered identical if they have the same name, strong name, culture, version, permission set, and binary contents.

In other words, you can repeat the definition in other databases and if everything is the same, then they are compatible.

Comment: Worth noting that if this is a UDT you do need in every database, along with creating it in your existing user databases, you would likely want to create it in the `model` database, so that any new databases created include the object too.